# Picasso загрузка изображения byte[]

Tags: android, picasso, обработка-изображений

Я имею ссылку типа **myapi/image?image_id={1}** при переходе на которую я получаю изображение в виде byte[]. Как с помощью Picasso я могу загрузить ее в ImageView?

UPD:
В консоли, при загрузке можно наблюдать:

`..../com.example.myapplication D/skia: —- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null
..../com.example.myapplication D/Picasso: Dispatcher batched [R0]+2839ms for error
..../com.example.myapplication D/Picasso: Main errored [R0]+3054ms Failed to decode stream.`

UPD2:
Может быть стоит посмотреть в сторону объекта Target?

UPD3: Формат ответа сервера:

[image: Response]

UPD4:
Картинка хранится на sql server в формате varbinary(max), ниже скрин из бд.[image: поле Data - это массив byte]

Чтобы получить картинку по id можно перейти по ссылке (https://vy5trnewne.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/api/images/getimage?imageId=2)[image: Код метода из контроллера, который возвращает картинку. Пишу на c#, но может пригодится]

Comment: Как то так, видимо: `Picasso.get().load("http://my.server.com/myapi/image?image_id={1}").into(imageView);` или не получается? Тогда поподробнее что к чему и в чём трудности...

Comment: @woesss это не работает для меня. Picasso не загружает картинку. Для уточнения, при переходе по ссылке **myapi/image?image_id={1}** api возвращает "array byte[]". Который потом необходимо конвертировать в Bitmap.

Comment: Любые данные (картинка, текст, всё что угодно) - это поток байтов, вопрос только в формате. Есть предположение, что _myapi_ требует авторизацию, токен, куки - тогда нужно их прикладывать и к запросу в Picasso. Как добавлять заголовки можно глянуть здесь: [Android Picasso library, How to add authentication headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273783/android-picasso-library-how-to-add-authentication-headers). Если не знаете - надо ли это, попробуйте открыть Вашу ссылку в обычном браузере: если откроется картинка - то не нужно, если покажет ошибку - то разбираться согласно ошибке.

Comment: @woesss авторизации нет, прикладывать ничего не нужно. Доступно всем. В браузере все отлично открывает. Разве что используется https соединение. Но это не должно влиять на работу. Решение пока не найдено! формат приатачил к вопросу.

Comment: Так это BASE64? Если нельзя сделать/попросить бекенд чтобы картинка отдавалась в нормальном виде, то пробуйте подобное решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42852617 или ищите дальше по этой теме.

Comment: @woesss автор api (мой хороший друг) утверждает, что отдает картинку в формате byte[]

Comment: Ссылку на пример такой картинки можно? Я уже писал, что любые данные - это массив/поток байтов, во что бы оно ни было кодировано. Да, то что у Вас на скрине - это явно BASE64.